# How to make *developing tourism* unambiguous?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

**The first obstacle to developing tourism in Iran**

This is the title of a newspaper article I have written. The phrase *developing tourism* appears ambiguous. I meant by this "pushing tourism to a more advanced level/spread tourism activities and industry".
Would you suggest me how to do so?

Comment: *promote tourism further?*

Comment: Many two-word phrases in a newspaper article are a bit ambigious, simply because many words have more than one meaning, and most headlines don't provide a lot of context. I don't have any problem with _developing tourism_, although I really wonder what you mean by "first" – I think that's where your ambiguity problem may really be.

Comment: I think ambiguity of this sort can be your friend.  Someone will read the headline and then ask, "I wonder which one they meant.  **I guess I'll have to read it.**"

Comment: @Jim - Good point. There's much that can go into a good headline: in addition to curiosity-piquing ambiguity, there can also be alliteration, puns, and vague cultural references. I just picked up today's newspaper, and they had a fashion piece discussing the longevity of the pleated skirt. The headline? _The Pleat Goes On_.

Comment: Thank you all pals, so I think I gonna leave it there. @J.R. by "first" I meant the first obstacle that should be addressed and removed

Answer (score 4):

**Promoting tourism** - though I don't think "developing" sounds bad.